# Xcode 8.2 shows build errors for Parse.framework and Bolts.framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, parse-platform

I have an Xcode project written in Obj-C which utilizes the Parse and Bolts framework as well as a few others. problem is I started getting a few very concerning errors where it seems that Xcode can't find the header files nor the frameworks. I tried removing their declarations in CocoaPods and manually installing the .framework files but that didn't seem to help either.
[image]

Comment: how did you add the frameworks? Did you forget to add the h files? Are the frameworks linked? What are your Linker Flags in build settings?

Comment: At first the frameworks were added manually and through CocoaPods (Parse, Bolts) but I switched to adding all of them using CocoaPods. The frameworks seem fine because all the files exist (I'm sorry, I'm kind of a beginner regarding this). How do I check for linked frameworks and Linker Flags?